# building phonegap does not include all plugins

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I have a cordova project that works well when I build and run it through eclipse. The project includes some plugins.

But building on the phonegap's building tool(https://build.phonegap.com) does not include the plugin called appPreferences which can be seen here https://github.com/macdonst/AppPreferences/tree/master/2.2.0

my cordova version is 2.0 and below you can see my xml part for this plugin

```
<feature name="applicationPreferences">
  <param name="applicationPreferences" value="com.simonmacdonald.prefs.AppPreferences"/>
</feature>

<!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
<plugins>
    <plugin name="applicationPreferences" value="com.simonmacdonald.prefs.AppPreferences"/>
</plugins>
```

I got this error message in logcat:

```
D/PluginManager(9433): exec() call to unknown plugin: applicationPreferences
```

Comment: which version you need to use this plugin ?

Comment: actually version doesn't matter much. instead of using phonegap's tool , I tried to build and create a proper apk file for google play and I managed to make it.

Answer (score 0):

hi **NEW PHONEGAP BUILD supports USER SUBMITTED PLUGIN**S and does not support user submitted plugin on older version (you are using phonrgap 2.0) So use latest version of Pgonegap (3.0) it solves your problem.  https://build.phonegap.com/plugins